# Issue with margins around a map in geopandas

Tags: matplotlib, geopandas

I cannot seem to solve some margin/location issue between the GeoPandas map and added annotations. Annotations are added by functions `addChartSignature` and `addTitle` and they cause a terrible layout.

I have managed to sort some vertical margins issue with a hack, see comment `### to deal with vertical margin issue`, however I cannot seem to deal with the margin on the left side: I would like the map, the signature and the title to be aligned with the left side with a very small margin (like on the right side).

I added the variable `righthspace` to move annotations right, but it doesn't help and it doesn't feel right anyway.

[image]

Below a code sample which summarize the issue

```
from __future__ import division

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

def addChartSignature(ax, vspace=0, righthspace=0):

    ax.annotate('', 
                xy=(0.97, 0.05 + vspace), 
                xycoords='figure fraction',
                xytext=(0.03 + righthspace,0.05 + vspace), 
                textcoords='figure fraction',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",
                                linewidth=0.7,
                                facecolor='grey', 
                                alpha=.7, 
                                edgecolor='grey'),
                horizontalalignment = 'center', 
                verticalalignment='bottom')

    ax.annotate(u" ©myCompany", 
                 xy=(0.5, 0.5), 
                 xycoords='figure fraction',
                 xytext= (0.03 + righthspace,0.01+vspace), 
                 textcoords='figure fraction',
                 ha="left", 
                 va="bottom", 
                 color = 'grey', 
                 alpha = .7, 
                 fontsize = 11)

    ax.annotate(u"Source: Internal", 
                 xy=(0.5, 0.5), 
                 xycoords='figure fraction',
                 xytext=(0.97,0.01+vspace), 
                 textcoords='figure fraction',
                 ha="right", 
                 va="bottom", 
                 color = 'grey', 
                 alpha = .7, 
                 fontsize = 11)

def addTitle(ax, vspace=0, righthspace=0):
    ax.annotate("My Chart Title", 
                 xy=(0.5, 0.5), 
                 xycoords='figure fraction',
                 xytext=(0.01+righthspace, 0.985+vspace), 
                 textcoords='figure fraction',
                 ha="left", 
                 va="top", 
                 color = 'black', 
                 alpha = .75, 
                 fontsize = 19, 
                 weight = 'bold')

path = geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
world = geopandas.read_file(path)
world = world[(world.pop_est>0) & (world.name!="Antarctica")]    

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_axes([0., 0., 1, 1])

ax = world.plot(color="lightgrey", ax=ax)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right',  size="3%", pad=-1.3) 
world.dropna().plot(
        column='pop_est', 
        ax=ax, 
        legend=True, 
        cax=cax, 
        cmap='RdYlGn',
        )

ax.grid(color='#F8F8F8')
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.set_yticklabels([])

### to deal with vertical margin issue
ax.set_aspect(aspect=4./3)
ax.margins(0)
ax.apply_aspect()
bbox = ax.get_window_extent().inverse_transformed(fig.transFigure)
w,h = fig.get_size_inches()
fig.set_size_inches(w*bbox.width, h*bbox.height)

addChartSignature(ax, righthspace = 0.05)
addTitle(ax, righthspace = 0.05)
```

Comment: The left side is actually the one which poses the least of a problem, because all artists can be aligned perfectly in a single coordinate system. It just got scrambled because of the "hack" that is used for the vertical direction. The overall problem here, namely to get all objects aligned perfectly and to adjust the figure size to have them fit while maintaining a fixed aspect for the axes, is utterly hard. There is no general solution for it. But one can of course calculate all parameters microscopically. I'm just not sure if anyone is willing to do that to give an answer here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for your feedback. The hack was the best I could come up on my own. But if you remove it, the plot becomes a simple geopandas map with annotations. I don’t understand why it’s that hard to cleanly align these objects